# How do i set textview to sharedpreference value

Tags: java, android

Hello I want to know how do i call a session from android

following is the code for my login page where is set the sessions

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Users user = mapper.load(Users.class,username);

           // System.out.println(user.getPassword());
           // System.out.println(username);
            try {
                if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                    //System.out.println("Correct");
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("userSession", username);
                    editor.commit();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
                            startActivity(new Intent(startActivity.this, accountActivity.class));
                        }
                    });
```

and after logging in it goes to the account page and the code for accound page is shown below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
      /* SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    String User=pref.getString("userSession", "Not Exist");
    System.out.println("Hello");
    System.out.println(User);
*/
    test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.streamingButton);
    testId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcomeTxt);
}
```

Now i want to know how do i set the textview to the logged in users username I have commented the sharedpreference code because it does not print the user id aswell. I dont understand why the commented code does not work

Comment: What is the Users user = mapper.load(Users.class,username); doing? Does it print the proper values in the first class?

Answer (score 1):

You needn't use SharedPreferences, just put data into intent. Then you can get data form onCreate of accountActivity.
See this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String userName = intent.getStringExtra("userName");

    test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.streamingButton);
    testId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcomeTxt);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of a text view easily using the setText() method. Or you can add text to the end (without overwriting the existing value) with append().

```
testId.setText("my value");
```

I'm not too sure about why the SharedPreferences doesn't work. Does the code for getting the application context work from the Runnable object? Do you need to pass a context to the Runnable, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Please use apply in place of commit where you are saving data in shared preference. Please remove only line SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit(); and uncomment your code. This will give you correct value store in shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `account page` to this!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(pref.contains("userSession") {

         String user = pref.getString("userSession", "UNDEFINED");
         textview.setText(user);

    }
}
```